# Illustrator: how to unbend a bent group?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

How can I get this back to its original, straight form?

[image: selection outline showing the original shape]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming these are bent via the 'Warp' tool, go to 'Object → Envelope Distort → Release' and this will undo the bend. Both bent and unbent shapes will be released as separate groups.

Answer (score 3):

Need to see the **Appearance panel** with the group selected.

Either remove the Warp Effect from the Appearance Panel, or Object > Envelope Distort > Release.

Answer (score 3):

My first suggestion would be to look at the Appearance panel, with the item you want to straighten selected. Is there an FX or Filter applied? Your solution may be as simple as removing an effect.


Here's a link to more about applying effects:
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/effects.html